# loading information from rest service into collectionview upon login using xamarin

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, collectionview

The app starts up with a button that tells the user to login. Upon valid login credentials (as confirmed by a rest API), I want to load information from another rest API call into a collectionview. I already stored the deconstructed json strings into a global variable. I know how to pre-initialize the collectionview but I don't know how to load it upon logging in. I'm pretty new to Xamarin so any help would be appreciated. I'm using MVVM. Any suggestions?

Comment: there are thousands of existing questions, samples, videos, etc that address how to do this.  Have you read any of them?  If you are already able to load the data from an API and deserialize it, then all you really need to do is set the CollectionView's ItemsSource

Comment: I couldn't find even one example of how to do this. Can you link one here please?

Comment: Do what?  What **specifically** do you not understand how to do?   Here is an entire guide to using CollectionView - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/

Comment: I read everything on that link before I even posted this. I am specifically wondering if anyone knows of an example where they are setting the CollectionView's ItemsSource upon deserialization. I don't see such an example on that link. Of course I searched for examples of this and I couldn't find any. I've seen examples of it being done during the constructor but not after deserialization. Please help.

Comment: After deserialization you will get a `List<model>`, then set this `List<model>` to the `CollectionView's ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 0):

just set the `ItemsSource`

```
// your ItemsSource must by an IEnumerable, like a List<T>
myCollectionView.ItemsSource = MyDataThatIGotFromMyAPI;
```